# Orthogonality of $e^{j\omega t}$

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Given a periodic signal $\tilde{f}(t)$ of period $T_0$, a Fourier coefficient $F_k$ is the projection $\tilde{f}(t)$ along the basis function $e^{jn\omega_0 t}$. The reason why the Fourier series coefficients completely characterizes the original signal $\tilde{f}(t)$ is because the set of basis functions $\{e^{jn\omega_0 t}: n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is orthogonal, i.e.
$$
\int_{T_0} e^{jn\omega_0 t} e^{-jm\omega_0 t} dt = \begin{cases}T_0, &n=m \\
0, & n\neq m\end{cases}
$$

Assuming that the above is correct, I am trying to understand why the Fourier transform also completely characterizes an aperiodic function $f(t)$, where the basis is now $\{e^{j\omega t}: \omega \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Now, the orthogonality principle requires solving the integral
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} e^{j\omega_1 t} e^{-j\omega_2 t} dt.
$$
However, this integral does not solve to the orthogonality results that I would like. Is my approach valid, or is there a flaw in my reasoning somewhere?

Comment: This integral does not converge. Nonetheless, you will often see it said that the integral is equal to the Dirac delta distribution $\delta(\omega_1-\omega_2)$ and this is the form the analogue of the orthogonality result for Fourier series takes. (This can be made precise, though it's more complicated than 'calculating the integral', and in practice, using this identity as a heuristic when calculating gives correct results.) For more information, see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340094/why-frac12-pi-int-infty-inftyeiwt-xdw-is-the-dirac-delta-func

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for.