# Autocorrelation function of Gaussian Random Process

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $(X_t : t \in \mathbb{R})$ be a continuous time, zero mean Gaussian random process with power spectral density $$S_X(\omega) = \frac{N_0}{2}.$$ I know that the autocorrelation function of $X_t$ should be $$R_X(\tau) = \frac{N_0}{2}\delta(\tau)$$ but I am not sure how to compute this for myself. The power spectral density is defined to be $$S_X(\omega) = \mathcal{F}\{R_X(\tau)\}$$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the fourier transform but I am not sure how to take the inverse fourier transform to get $R_X(\tau)$. How does one go about such a calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the inverse Fourier transform over $\mathbb{R}$ can be computed as an integral:
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}[g](x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi{i}x\xi}g(\xi)d\xi$$
(Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Inverse_Fourier_transform_as_an_integral)). In your case, $g(\xi)=N_0/2=\text{const.}$, so you can pull it outside the integral, and you are left with:
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}[g](x)=(N_0/2)\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi{i}x\xi}d\xi.$$
The value of this integral is exactly what you want. See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1343859/398989).