# Integrals and sums

Tags: integration

I have a question about the second answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343859/why-does-integrating-a-complex-exponential-give-the-delta-function).
The last step should be

$$  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(w) \delta (w-\hat w)\mathrm{d}w = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(w) \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty   e^{i(w-\hat{w})t}\,\mathrm{d}t \right) \,\mathrm{d}w$$

After derivation of the equation, it is:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty   e^{i(w-\hat{w})t}\,\mathrm{d}t= \delta (w- \hat w) $$

Is that correct?

What if there were sums instead of integrals, please? How to get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{t}   e^{i(w-\hat{w})t}= \delta (w- \hat w) $$
?

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel).

Comment: Which of the equations in the link do you excatly mean, please?

Comment: To be honest I think you should read the article as a whole, as well as the Fejér kernel article to which it links, to familiarize yourself with not only the equations but relevant concepts. The important point is that we acquire a family of functions integrating to $1$ that pointwise approximate $\delta(x)$.

Comment: I went through the article, but I still do not get it.